# How to extract still images from VOB file

Tags: video, image-processing

How can I extract still images (jpeg?) from a VOB video file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with [transcode](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/man1/transcode.1.html):

```
transcode -x mpeg2 -i video.vob -y im -F jpg -w 100 -o images
```

`-F` of course is the output, `-w` is the quality, `-i` the video file, `-x` the transcoding. `-o` is the output file base name (if this is not specified the default location is `/dev/null`). For more see the manual page. Also have a look at [transcode export](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/man1/transcode_import.1.html)

Installation:

```
sudo apt-get install transcode
```